# Newbie "first date formatting" script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started experimenting with JavaScript yesterday. This would've been my first script, yet it doesn't function properly when opened as an html file. I can's spot anything wrong with it, have gone through it four times, any suggestions?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Displaying the current time and date (formatted version)</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">

<!-- Hide from browser that do not support JavaScript

var today = new Date();

var month = today.getMonth();

var displayMonth="";

switch (month) {
   case 0 :
     displayMonth = "January"
     break
   case 1 :
     displayMonth = "February"
     break
   case 2 :
     displayMonth = "March"
     break
   case 3 :
     displayMonth = "April"
     break
   case 4 :
     displayMonth = "May"
     break 
   case 5 :
     displayMonth = "June" 
     break
   case 6 :
     displayMonth = "July"
     break 
   case 7 :
     displayMonth = "August"
     break
   case 8 :
     displayMonth = "September"
     break
   case 9 :
     displayMonth = "October"
     break 
   Case 10 :
     displayMonth = "November"
     break
   Case 11 : 
     displayMonth = "December"
     break

   default: displayMonth = "INVALID"
}

   var hours = today.getHours();
   var minutes = today.getMinutes();
   var greeting;
   var ampm;

   if (hours <= 11) {
     greeting = "Good morning!";
     ampm="a.m."; 

     if (hours == 0) {
       hours= 12;
     }
  }

     else if (hours > 11 && hours < 18) {
       greeting = "Good afternoon!";
       ampm = "p.m.";

       if (hours > 12 ) {
          hours -= 12;
       }
     }

     else if (hours > 17 && hours < 21) {
       greeting = "Good evening!";
       ampm = "p.m.";
       hours -= 12;
     }

     else if (hours > 20) {
       greeting = "Good Night!";
       ampm = "p.m.";
       hours -= 12;
     }

    if (minutes < 10) {
       minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

var displayGreeting = displayMonth + " "
       + today.getDate() + ", "
       + today.getYear()
       + " - " + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm

document.writeln(displayGreeting)  

// --> Finish hiding
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<B> HELP <B>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: `Case` - replace with `case`.

Comment: add ";" to var displayGreeting

Comment: hit F12 on keyboard and get used to using console to look for errors while developing. Read up on all the features within the console ... learning how to debug is as important as how to write the code and will save lots of time and guesswork in the long run

Comment: Thnaks guys for the tips. Will focus on debugging a lot more. Thanks Ren for your input aswell! Hope to irritate you guys soon with another newbie mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, i suggest not using such a long `case` declaration for getting current month, instead use the following

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var month = monthNames[today.getMonth()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two times `Case` instead of `case`, and javascript is `case-sensitive` (no pun intended there..)

You also forgot to show your greetings message I think.

A JSfiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/tg6ofrvr/2/

(I used jquery only to show the message since document print is not allowed in jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

Your very own code, just a small modifications. :)

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Displaying the current time and date (formatted version)</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
   <!-- Hide from browser that do not support JavaScript
   var today = new Date();
   var month = today.getMonth();
   var displayMonth="";
   var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
   var hours = today.getHours();
   var minutes = today.getMinutes();
   var greeting;
   var ampm;

   if (hours <= 11) {
     greeting = "Good morning!";
     ampm="a.m."; 

     if (hours == 0) {
       hours= 12;
     }
   }

     else if (hours > 11 && hours < 18) {
       greeting = "Good afternoon!";
       ampm = "p.m.";

       if (hours > 12 ) {
          hours -= 12;
       }
     }

     else if (hours > 17 && hours < 21) {
       greeting = "Good evening!";
       ampm = "p.m.";
       hours -= 12;
     }

     else if (hours > 20) {
       greeting = "Good Night!";
       ampm = "p.m.";
       hours -= 12;
     }

    if (minutes < 10) {
       minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    var displayGreeting = months[month] + " " + today.getDate() + ", " + today.getFullYear() + " -  " + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm +"<br />"+ greeting;
    document.writeln(displayGreeting)
    // --> Finish hiding
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!--B> HELP <B-->
</BODY>
</HTML>
```